# Como selecionar uma string aleatória de uma lista em C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, lista

Basicamente, pretendia escolher uma Pergunta aleatória da 'Lista de Perguntas'e quando escrevo o código, dá-me erro na parte a negrito (a que está dentro dos **).

```
    private void EscolhaDaPergunta()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        ListaPerguntas =**{ "Pergunta1","Pergunta2","Pergunta3","Pergunta4"};**
        int index = random.Next(ListaPerguntas.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(ListaPerguntas[index]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode criar a variável na louca assim, precisa usar a sintaxe correta pra declará-la, dizer que tipo de objeto está criando com o tipo de dado que terá dentro dele.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var random = new Random();
        var ListaPerguntas = new List<string> { "Pergunta1", "Pergunta2", "Pergunta3", "Pergunta4" };
        WriteLine(ListaPerguntas[random.Next(ListaPerguntas.Count)]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Xroean). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uJwlwn). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Syntax2.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! :)